# Approval process that send an alert email or another based on a condition

Tags: approval-process, email-alert

I need to have an approval process to aprov/reject a record but at the same time I need that if the approver user not respond before 72 hours, the record is automatically rejected.

I have an approval process. In adittion, I have a process builder that has a scheduled action that calls an apex class that reject the lock record.

I also need that if the user manually rejects the record, another user receives an email alert. But if the registration is automatically rejected (by the Apex class), the user receives another different email alert.

I don't where or how establish this difference between the alert emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe create a custom formula field, in which it will maintain time difference between approval sent & current time.

Then depending upon value of that field, you can take further actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But where you put the alert emails? Now I have one alert in the method (the 'automatic' email alert) and another in the final actions of the approval process (but this is wrong because always send this alert email).

But I can't put the second alert email (the 'manual' alert) in the method of the classe because don't send the email until 72 hours and I need the alert be send when the record will be rejected/approved.